# hide some section in admin panel magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to hide some section of the admin panel > configurations

how to do that? 
like there is a section called ( about us ) and it's the theme developer. I want to hide it. and some other things as well

magento 1.9

Comment: @muzramn, sv3n gave a good point on my attempt to answer your question. Though, I now need to admit that I do not exactly know what particular area you want to hide (since `about us` is no section I'm actual aware about). Disallowing modules from roles certainly does require that the (custom) modules are well written and/or do not rely already given menu structures in some way (i.e. a module that is adding a text field somewhere inside another modules config might be tricky to get disallowed in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hiding elements / menu sections via the modules `system.xml` (even though this might be necessary in some cases) I'd suggest you to create new a new user and user group and assign permissions based on the requirement for this user.

This should be a preferred way if the user that is to be restricted is nowhere close admin-permissions and/or the menu that is to be disabled for one user is required by other users.

You can create new user groups (aka "roles") from `System > Permissions > Roles` You can then switch the `Resource Access` to `Custom` in the second tab and grant privileges to needed areas only:
[image]

The new role than can be applied to a particular user under `System > Permissions > Users` in the tab `User Role`.

Comment: Definitly correct, but I doubt that ACL resources are defined in `adminhtml.xml` for  _"about us"_ sections.

Comment: @sv3n, sounds valid - let me verify that one

Comment: Roles is definitely the best way to do this. Don't modify the core files and lose access to parts of your website, just adjust what you want to see and log into that account instead.